# how to apply a custom mode to mapbox-gl-draw when writing a html which uses GL draw to draw a feature

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

On the github of the mapbox-gl-draw, I've seen that draw provides an interface for writing and hooking in custom modes, but how does the custom modes actually be used on the browser? For example, if I want to write a mode which can draw a curve line, how can I add this new mode to draw's original modes and be used in browser? I'm new to mapbox gl, and hope anyone can help me on this, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

download the zip on the github, and edit the js file in src. At last, use the nodejs to execute "npm run build" and generate a new mapbox-gl-draw.js in the dist, which can be used in the html by writing